# Getting nicknames of users of my Discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I can see the names, ids and user numbers of the servers where my bot is located, but how can I get the list of users (nicknames)?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`guild.members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) in order to get all members and then use the [`nickname`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname) property to receive their nicknames. Finally I removed all bots with a simple [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const members = (await message.guild.members.fetch())
  .filter((m) => !m.user.bot)
  .map((m) => m.displayName);
console.log(members);
```

Working example as a *command*:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content === "!list") {
    const members = (await message.guild.members.fetch())
      .filter((m) => !m.user.bot)
      .map((m) => m.displayName);
    console.log(members);
  }
});

client.login("your-token");
```

Thanks to [@MrMythical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079/mrmythical) who suggested using [`displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) only. That property automatically returns the normal [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname) when no nickname has been set for a user.

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my [answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) when it has resolved your problem ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure `m.displayName` shows nickname, and username if there is no nickname itself

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the hint I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Users do not have `nicknames`, only guild members, if you are trying to fetch a list of server member nicknames.

You can use the code snippet from below:

```js
const map = message.guild.members.cache.filter(c=> !c.member.user.bot).map(c=>c.displayName).join('\n');
console.log(map)
```

The

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(c=> !c.member.user.bot)
```

Filters bots from the list, the

```js
.map(c=>c.displayName).join('\n');
```

maps the data and only the user nicknames and joins them by paragraph breaks.

If there are any issues, please comment!